# Does the sort direction of a MongoDB TTL index matter?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In other words, is there a difference between

```
db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

and

```
db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": -1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

?

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) do not seem to mention anything regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

**With a single field index** - The order won't matter. If they are close together in ascending order, they will also be close together in descending order.

**How TTL works**

```
//find the expireAfterSeconds value from collection indexes
var expireAfterSeconds = db.eventlog.getIndexes().filter(function(i){
    return i.hasOwnProperty('expireAfterSeconds');
})[0].expireAfterSeconds;

// epoch time
var startTime = new Date(1970,0,1);
// end time
var endTime = new Date(Date.now() - expireAfterSeconds*3600);
db.eventlog.remove({lastModifiedDate: { $gt: startTime, $lte: endTime }});
```

**Reference:** [ttl.cpp source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/b531f537cf383ec6a70ddbee9f6d2902e7498b96/src/mongo/db/ttl.cpp#L273-L308)

Full TTL explanation: http://hassansin.github.io/working-with-mongodb-ttl-index

Answer (score 0):

> A TTL index supports queries in the same way non-TTL indexes do.

the sorting  order  just **affect  your  query result  order** . will not affect the TTL behavior  .

> TTL indexes expire documents after the specified number of seconds has
>   passed since the indexed field value; i.e. the expiration threshold is
>   the indexed field value plus the specified number of seconds.

so  they are the same  for  TTL  indexes  in your conditions.

By the way .  the  documents  be deleted immediately when use  TTL  indexes

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60
>   seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the
>   period between the expiration of the document and the running of the
>   background task

Comment: You quoted from the link I posted already in my question. `will not affect the TTL behavior` where is your reference for this?

Comment: the documents  is the best teacher .  please re-examine its  behavior   .Read the date type values in the index and remove expired documents from the collection  .the indexes  is just  to speed up queries  for   background thread  .